# Lemmatizing in a list comprehension if word is less than X

Tags: python, list-comprehension, wordnet

I have the following function that receives a list of word tokens, collects the Parts of Speech tag in a format readable by WordNet, and uses that to lemmatize each token - I'm applying that to a list of lists of word tokens:

```
from nltk import pos_tag
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def getWordNetPOS (POStag):
    def is_noun(POStag):
        return POStag in ['NN', 'NNS', 'NNP', 'NNPS']
    def is_verb(POStag):
        return POStag in ['VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ']
    def is_adverb(POStag):
        return POStag in ['RB', 'RBR', 'RBS']
    def is_adjective(POStag):
        return POStag in ['JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS']

    if is_noun(POStag):
        return wn.NOUN
    elif is_verb(POStag):
        return wn.VERB
    elif is_adverb(POStag):
        return wn.ADV
    elif is_adjective(POStag):
        return wn.ADJ
    else:
        # if not noun, verb, adverb or adjective, return noun
        return wn.NOUN

# lemmatize word tokens
def lemmas (wordtokens):
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    POStag = pos_tag(wordtokens)
    wordtokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token[0], getWordNetPOS(token[1]))
                  for token in POStag]

    return wordtokens

lemmatizedList = []
mylist = [['this','is','my','first','sublist'],['this','is','my','second','sublist']]

for ls in mylist:
    x = lemmas(ls)
    lemmatizedList.append(x)
```

I want to find a way to limit the lemmatization to tokens of a set length (i.e. 2), but crucially I also want to retain the original form of any words less than this threshold. The closest I have got is to add `if len(token[0])>2` on to the end of the `wordtokens` list comprehension within the `lemmas` function, but this only returns the lemmatized tokens. Similarly, I have tried to add something akin to `else token for token in POStag` after the `if` statement, but I get a syntax error. For clarity, this is what I mean:

```
wordtokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token[0], getWordNetPOS(token[1]))
              for token in POStag if len(token[0])>2
              else token for token in POStag]
```

I'm hoping its a simple error and a bit of a python blind spot on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just a 'blind spot'.

You have to restructure the list comprehension and condition a bit:

```py
wordtokens = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(token[0], getWordNetPOS(token[1])) if len(token[0]) > 2 else token
              for token in POStag]
```

---

Explanation:

The list comprehension has to keep all the tokens, so you don't want to add a condition with `if`.

```py
wordtokens = [<tokenoperation> for token in POStag]
```

Now, you want to change the operation based on the token length, so you only change the part of `tokenoperation`, so that it only modifies the token:

```py
lemmatizer.lemmatize(token[0], getWordNetPOS(token[1])) if len(token[0]) > 2 else token
```

You could also add some parantheses like this, to make it more clear:

```py
wordtokens = [
    (
        lemmatizer.lemmatize(token[0], getWordNetPOS(token[1]))
        if len(token[0]) > 2
        else token
    )
    for token in POStag
]
```

Some documentation/examples: See section *Using Conditional Logic* on this [realpython.com](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) page.

Comment: Great! I thought as much. Reconstructing it from scratch it's easy to spot. I think the problem arose because I wrote the all inclusive code months ago and am only just returning to it!! Note to self: make better notes! Thanks